# Whether assigning smart pointer to _variant_t requires a manual AddRef()?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, smart-pointers, variant

Here is an example snippet:

```
_variant_t var;

var.vt = VT_UNKNOWN;

var.punkVal = unknownInterfaceSmartPointer;

unknownInterfaceSmartPointer->AddRef(); // Question Statement

// Setting unknownInterfaceSmartPointer to some other container
```

Whether manual AddRef is really needed here? Following will is better way than this:

```
_variant_t var(unknownInterfaceSmartPointer.GetInterfacePointer());
```

your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you directly assign to `punkVal` member (as in your first snippet) then you need an `AddRef()` - noone will do it for you. A much better way would be to use `operator=()` member of `_variant_t`:

```
_variant_t var;
var = unknownInterfaceSmartPointer.GetInterfacePointer();
```

or do as you suggest - use a conversion constructor:

```
_variant_t var(unknownInterfaceSmartPointer.GetInterfacePointer());
```

Both latter variants are good and don't require an `AddRef()` in your code - it will be done inside `_variant_t` implementation. Furthermore, they are beneficial because if you reassign to the same variant the implementation will do proper cleanup for you:

```
_variant_t var;
// if you assign a BSTR or smart pointer here
// you want it to be properly released later
var = whatever1();
// this will do the proper release of the previously
// stored stuff and then assign the new value
var = whatever2();
```